# Error in upgrading rpy2 python package to version 3.3.3

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, pip, rpy2

I upgraded my already installed rpy2 package from version 3.2.6 to 3.3.3 and observed the following issue:

```
Error: C stack usage  454466426436 is too close to the limit
Error: C stack usage  454466426484 is too close to the limit
Error: C stack usage  454466426484 is too close to the limit
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
During startup - Warning message:
unable to restore saved data in .RData
Error: C stack usage  454466426372 is too close to the limit
Fatal error: unable to initialize the JIT
```

Comment: When do you get the error? When importing the rpy2 module, or when running some particular code? Which version of R do you have installed? Which OS are you using?

Comment: I get this error when importing rpy2 module. I am using R 3.4.4 on an Linux Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is there any `.RData` file in the working directory? Which is the message that you obtain after renaming it?

Answer (score 1):

You should update R to a newer version, at least R-3.6.x, as suggested by the main developer of the package in this [issue](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/683) on Github. I was not able to reproduce your error with the new version R-4.0.0. I hope this fixes your problem.